Microservices architecture - wrapper service?
How common are wrapper services/APIs in a microservice architecture? From my personal experience, it feels like it's an anti-pattern but perhaps I am missing some details?
I am working on splitting up a tightly coupled architecture into a microservice setup. Hence, each service will have its own database if needed, otherwise fully stateless.
The client uses some 3rd party integrations that have their own service, since they all provide similar but differently formatted responses. The client is insisting on building a wrapper service on top of all integrations that would be responsible for calling the said integrations (like a proxy service) and map the responses to a common model.
I can perhaps see what the added value of the consistent response is (although it can be achieved differently) but I am having a hard time finding pro arguments to be on board with the wrapper idea.
Also, these integrations do not need to always be there - one customer can decide how many and which integrations they are willing to pay for.

I am working on splitting up a tightly coupled architecture into a microservice setup The strangler fig is common pattern when you are migrating from a monolith to a mircoservice architecture. Are you sure that they are not referring to this façade when they say wrapper service?

@PeterCsala Yeah, I am sure. In this context, the wrapper service is a standalone API that would call the other integrations and map those responses to a common one. But it does nothing more than that. The response models of the integarations themselves can also be adjusted and synce, there are no restrictions there.

And do you have one wrapper service per microservice or only a single wrapper service for all microservices (like in the api gateway pattern)?

@PeterCsala It would be one for 3 microservices out of 15.

The only serious reason (as in, the other ones are because a programmer thinks its cool, or has been reading blogs on the internet) is if you think the API should be interchangeable with another providing the same service and you will want to cater for that. eg if you have a Google search integration and you think you might want to swap it for Bing at some time.
Otherwise you're just making work for yourself, YAGNI style. You may think you want a common interface so clients can call any of the services with the same code, but all you've done is shift the effort of calling the service to a proxy - not actually saved yourself anything, just moved it elsewhere.
So YMMV depending on your circumstances, but ask yourself what business benefits this would achieve.

THank you for your reply, I definetly feel the same way. Having so many points of failure will break the dev & testing flow. I think the main resoning was "it will be easy for the FE to communicate with the BE" but I always felt that FE should be customizable for your client and not the other way around

TBH If making a more consistent interface for the FE devs to use is a requirement, then it can make sense to wrapper the back end calls up like this, you take the pain so those javascript devs (bless) won;t mess it up. I wouldn't make a heap of microservices for this though, 1 bigger one that calls whichever backend as needed would be more maintainable in such a case.

Yeah that is also an option I suppose. But these integrations are so large and it will make BE dev's life more difficult.
